# How to switch to the Nth previous unique branch in Git?

Tags: git, shell, version-control, branch, git-switch

Lets say I have 3 branches in my repository: `main`, `develop` and `feature`. Now, suppose I have switched my working branch in the following order: from `main`, to `develop`, to `feature`, back to `develop`, and to `feature` again.

From this position I would like to go back to my `main` branch without having to write `main` so that in theory I can forget the name of my branch. The [switch command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) can come a long way with the `@{-N}` notation to refer to the N-th last branch/commit, like so:

- `git switch -` will take me to branch `develop` (same as `git switch @{-1}`)
- `git switch @{-1}` will take me to branch `develop`
- `git switch @{-2}` will take me to branch `feature`
- `git switch @{-3}` will take me to branch `develop`
- `git switch @{-4}` will take me to branch `main`

As you can see, this lists all your previous working branches. However, since I will be switching between `develop` and `feature` multiple times before wanting to go back to `main`, I would have to remember the precise amount of times I have switched between `develop` and `feature` since I left `main`. I would like to be able to refer to a previous *unique* branch, such that something like `git switch @{-2} --unique` would take me to `main`, but that option does not exist for the `git switch` command at least.

I have found a handy trick to [list your most recently-used branches using Git](http://ses4j.github.io/2020/04/01/git-alias-recent-branches/), and that will list your branches uniquely. Maybe it is possible to take that idea to create a way to switch to the Nth previous unique branch?

Comment: Not sure what you want to accomplish.... `git checkout -` can help you switch between `develop` and `feature` without having to specify anything about them (just `git checkout -`..... something I learned recently, actually). So.... if you want to then get out of this never-ending cycle between the 2 branches: `git checkout main`.

Comment: If you want to get back to main, why not simply `git switch main`? Remembering `main` sounds a lot easier than keeping track of how many unique branches were visited since main was last checked out.

Comment: @eftshift0 Of course I can use `git checkout main`, but I was looking for a way to not be required to type the name of that branch.

Comment: `git switch m<TAB>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is still to use `git switch main`. But if you really want to …

Should be simple enough (although will start to fail if output of `git reflog` changes – it's not intended to be parsed)

##### Get unique branch names from reflog:

```
git reflog | awk '/checkout: moving from/ && !seen[$NF]++ {print $NF}'
```

##### Select n'th entry

```
git reflog | awk … | sed -n "${n}p"
```

or

```
git reflog | awk … | awk "NR==${n}"
```

##### Make it an alias (`sn` – "switch n")

```
git config --global alias.sn '!f() {
  branch="$(git reflog | awk '\''/checkout: moving from/ && !seen[$NF]++ {print $NF}'\'' | awk "NR==${1:-1}")";
  git switch "$branch";
}; f'
```

(n will default to 1 – the most recent branch)

##### Use it

```
git sn 5 # go to 5th last branch
git sn   # go to previous branch
```